# How to fetch column names count from Tables based on columns passed into IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, count

I am trying to fetch column count from `all_tab_columns` for particular columns passed into IN clause like:

```
select count(COLUMN_NAME) 
  from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
 WHERE owner='SA' and COLUMN_NAME IN ('CASE_REPORTER2SITE', 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG') 
 GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME 
HAVING COLUMN_NAME IN ('CASE_REPORTER2SITE', 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG')
 ORDER BY DECODE (COLUMN_NAME, 'CASE_REPORTER2SITE', 1 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG', 2)
```

Here when both the columns exist in the database, It gives me count of both columns in 2 rows.

**RESULT:**

```
COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)
------------------
2
4
```

But, when I pass one existing and 1 non existing column like:

```
select count(COLUMN_NAME) 
  from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
 WHERE owner='SA' and COLUMN_NAME IN ('CASE_XYZ', 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG') 
 GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME 
HAVING COLUMN_NAME IN ('CASE_XYZ', 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG')
 ORDER BY DECODE (COLUMN_NAME, 'CASE_XYZ', 1 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG', 2)
```

(Assume `CASE_XYZ` does not exist).
It gives me count result in 1 row.

**RESULT:**

```
COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)
------------------
4
```

**Expected Result:**

```
COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)
------------------
0
4
```

How to get the count as 0 for the particular column if it does not exist?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this using `left join`.  With a smart subquery, this eliminates the `in` and the `decode()` in the `order by` as well.

I would phrase the query as:

```
with cols as (
      select 'CASE_REPORTER2SITE' as col, 1 as ordering from dual union all
      select 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG', 2 as ordering from dual
     )
select cols.col, count(atc.col_name)
from cols left join
     all_tab_columns atc
     on cols.col = atc.col_name and atc.owner = 'SA'
group by cols.col
order by max(cols.ordering);
```

Note:  I also included the column name in the output, because I think that is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm, the only way I can think of is joining the all_Tab_columns table with a self created from dual, left outer join to keep those who are null, and put 0 when null like this:

```
select t.column_name,case when count is null then 0 else count end from (
SELECT 'CASE_XYZ' as colname from dual
union
SELECT 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG' from dual) t
left outer join (
select column_name, count(COLUMN_NAME) as count from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE owner='SA' and COLUMN_NAME IN ('CASE_XYZ', 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG')
GROUP  BY COLUMN_NAME HAVING COLUMN_NAME IN ('CASE_XYZ', 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG')
ORDER BY DECODE (COLUMN_NAME, 'CASE_XYZ', 1 'PRIMARY2BUS_ORG', 2)) s
on t.colname = s.column_name
```